# Single email is not enabled for your organization or profile.: []

Tags: apex, mass-email, dupeblocker

caused by:

> System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0;
>   first error: NO_MASS_MAIL_PERMISSION, Single email is not enabled for
>   your organization or profile.: []

Error is coming while installing managed package even user profile having 'Mass Email and Manage Users Permissions

Comment: Means now in current org Emails are masked so when we do data loading Email will not go to actual user even if we set 'All Email' setting beacuse emails are maskjed.But when i will do same for production then email will thrown to actual user.Please suggest how to proceed

Answer (score 18):

In Setup -> Email Administration -> Deliverability, you have to set:

`Access to Send Email (All Email Services)` to `All email`

Comment: but when we will deploy the same in production then mail will be send to actual users which we don't want.Now in current org email are Masked.Please suggest how to proceed in Producution with data load

Comment: Means now in current org Emails are masked so when we do data loading Email will not go to actual user even if we set 'All Email' setting.But when i will do same for production then email will thrown to actual user.Please suggest how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

If you install a managed package that sends emails to users, it will send emails to users. You cannot change that (unless the managed code or other automation is editable, which is rarely done). Most email clients enable filtering aka rules, which is a poor solution, but it is the only solution I can think of for your situation. (I assume this is what you mean by "Error is coming while installing managed package". If the email is sent one time by the installation process, just tell the recipients to ignore the one-time email.)